# Can't run sqlite query with node 14.16.1

Tags: sqlite, npm

I have a known good database that I copied over from Linux. I installed sqlite3 from source and with prebuilt libraries:

```
 npm install --build-from-source sqlite3
```

I ended up with sqlite3@5.0.2.

when I run sql from my app it complains that it can't find a table I know is there:

Database {}
SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: REVISIONS

After digging around it seems like this is my sqlite binary distributed with the source:

`node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-win32-x64\node_sqlite3.node`

When I try to run it in bash for windows, I get this error:

```
$ node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-win32-x64/node_sqlite3.node
bash: node_modules/sqlite3/lib/binding/napi-v3-win32-x64/node_sqlite3.node: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

Update:

I tried on Debian and I get the same error,

```
Database {}
SQLITE_ERROR: no such table: revisions
GET / 200 59.316 ms - 2447
```

So it might be a code issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was feeding sqlite an non-fully qualified path for the database file. Since sqlite generates databases on the fly, it created a database wherever it was looking and then dutifully noted that the table wasn't there. I did this admittedly common idiom to fix it:

```
const path = require("path");
const db_name = path.join(__dirname, "data", "apptest.db");
```

etc.